# VirtualBox suddenly lost all network interfaces

Tags: networking, ubuntu, virtualbox

I have Windows 10 host and Ubuntu 16.04 guest on my virtualBox I am using NAT as network configuration. Everything was working fine until I suddenly lost my netwrok interface and network connection. 
When I type `ifconfig` I get the following result:

```
lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:20 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:20 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:1936 (1.9 KB)  TX bytes:1936 (1.9 KB)
```

However `ifconfig -a` gives the following result:

```
enp0s3    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 08:00:27:77:25:c9  
          BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:20 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:20 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:1936 (1.9 KB)  TX bytes:1936 (1.9 KB)
```

I googled this problem and most answers refer to **write_net_rules** and **70-persistent-net.rules** files that don't have !

Also when I do `ifup enp0s3`I get `Unknown interface enp0s3`.

**EDIT: Network settings**
[image: Network settings]

Comment: Can you please post a screenshot of the Settings -> Network tab with expanded Advanced settings?

Comment: @fragamemnon I updated my question with the network settings

Comment: Could you try reconfiguring the adapter to Bridged, or spinning up a second, bridged adapter? I've had problems with VBox's networking engine before and thus now stick to bridged adapters.

Comment: I did what you suggested. It didn't solve my issue

Comment: Frankly, I had to troubleshoot similar problems about an year ago and I didn't document it. If you're willing to bear with me in troubleshooting, could you post the interface configuration in `/etc/network/interfaces`?

Comment: thanks for your help. in interfaces I only have `auto lo` `iface lo inet loopback`

Comment: In that case, you have to manually input all the settings. This might be a valuable resource: https://wiki.debian.org/NetworkConfiguration 

If that works for you, I'll post it as an answer.

Comment: Remember that Ubuntu's `/etc/network/interfaces` is likely to be empty because the rest is configured via NetworkManager. It might be worth investigating that first.

Comment: @fragamemnon I tried doing it manually it still didn't work ...

Comment: @grawity I will check that

Comment: @grawity thanks for orienting me to the network manager, it is the one who caused the problem along with wpasupplicant. I will post what I did as an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some reason, I lost my network manager and the wpasupplicant.

I manually downloaded network manager, network manager gnome and wpasupplicant packages on my host from https://packages.ubuntu.com .
I then copied them to my virtualBox under `/var/cache/apt/archives/`. 
Finally I did `sudo apt install wpasupplicant`, `sudo apt install network-manager` and `sudo apt install network-manager-gnome`. I then rebooted and everything started working again.